# How remove date from field? (Logstash)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have this field:

> "log" => "2016-08-03 14:00:54,448 [DEBUG] District ID for Customer
>   filter: 161943\r",

How to remove the date from that? My code doesn't work:

```
mutate {
  gsub => ["log", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}", ""]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but with `ruby` filter you can try:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event['log'] = event['log'].split(' ')[2..-1].join(' ')"
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont know how it works, but WORKS :) Thank you. Is it safe? Or maybe you can tell me how delete first 24 characters from log. Because always my logs start with date.

Comment: That code split string by space, remove first 2 elements and recreate string from array by concatenating with space. Just to delete 24 characters you can change it as  code => "event['log'] = event['log'][24..-1]". But are you sure 14:00:54,`448`will always be 3 characters?

Comment: I think yes but i am not sure.

Comment: Then the answer is OK to use.

Comment: So if i am sure is 24 characters this code => "event['log'] = event['log'][24..-1]" is better?

Comment: Yes it will be more efficient.